# C# attributes, is there a keypress attribute?

Tags: c#

I'm coming from intermediate java level and I wanted to spend some time tonight learning C#, what I essentially want to do is something along the lines of (psuedo code):

```
[KeyPressEvent("KeyPressed")]
private void KeyPressed(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs args) {
    if (args.KeyPressed == VK_K) {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

My C# vernacular is not up to part, but on that notion I haven't done a whole lot of Java projects that related to events (or Observers as I believe they're referred to as).

---

**Edit**

Ok I  understand that what I thought attributes were is wrong, I thought they were simply another way to subscribe to events, but it is simply something that was provided by the 3rd party framework I'm working with.

Comment: There is no such magical attribute for this in the BCL. While one *could* be created I suppose (e.g. it's really no different in concept than a WebMethod), events should normally be registered directly to the applicable event source.

Comment: Please consider removing "new here" and story of your life from the post (at least fix title).

Comment: I trimmed everything down, drinky drink make too much typey type.

Comment: As i said in my comment, tell us which UI Framework you're using, there are ways to do this in each Framework but you need to tell us which one (winform, wpf, mvc or webforms)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, attributes have nothing to do with events, you'd just have to register your method to the event but an attribute would do nothing, attributes add metadata to your code, they don't "do" anything but they're there so that other code can read them at runtime and then do something based on that.

If you really wanted you could so something that auto registers the event based on an attribute but that's just as much work as not doing it or as doing the same thing without attribute with a naming convention

Comment: Ok that was my misunderstanding of interpreting existing code for what I'm doing.  Is there an event I can register to that monitors keyboard input?

Comment: Yes but you need to give us more info, there is no "C#" GUI, there are plenty of UI, what are you using? winform, wpf, webform, mvc? What is your project type?

Comment: I would like to monitor key events from a game window, I thought there might simply be an event for if my program is running to hook to a KeyPressed event, but it doesn't look like that is the case.  I probably just need to find something in the 3rd party utility that monitors this event.

Comment: A game or something else doesn't matter, what matters is what project type this is, what api are you using to create your game? What is your window made of? Is it a winform window or a wpf window? (When you created your project, what project type did you use?)

Comment: If you don't know the answer to any of that, go into the code file of your window project and list all the using statements

Comment: Still not entirely sure what you're looking for, it's a .NET 3.5 application using C#.  The game window hooks are a 3rd party api, so all I'm trying to do is program a plugin for this 3rd party utility, similar to how you can create plugins using LUA and WoW, only the plugin platform is 3rd party developed rather than published by the game developer.  This is the API website: http://www.decaldev.com/ and here is the code I have so far: https://bitbucket.org/akevit/ntools/src

Comment: Then this has nothing to do with .net, if you're writing a plugin to a game you're not going to retrieve the keyboard info the same way as you do in other projects and this dépends only on the documentation for the API you're using, if they're not providing any doc on how to do this with THEIR api (unrelated to anything .net offers to begin with) you're very likely out of luck

Answer (score 4):

C# has nothing that inherently associates events with attributes.  Maybe the 3rd party framework you are using evaluates attributes to automatically hook up events but the C# language and Microsoft's UI frameworks do not do this.

Comment: This is likely what's happening, the existing code I have to learn from is a mix of everything and there is no documentation from the 3rd party framework aside from what I've parsed with SandCastle.  Is there an event I can register to though for keypresses?  Something like `KeyPressEvent += WhatHappens;` ?